# overwrite javascript variable from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to overwrite the `status` variable from the ajax call.. i tried in this way but its not overwriting the `status` variable... Please help me.

```
 function myfunction()
            {
                var status = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>login/ajaxsessioncheck/",
                    success: function(data)
                    { 
                            status="new value"; 

                    }
                });
                alert(status)
            return status;
            }
```

Comment: you can't do that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: You can't return from an async function like that.

Comment: @adeneo so how to solve this issue in some other way?  i really need to solve this

Comment: @ArunPJohny Question which you are showing is diffrent then my one. Did you understand my question?

Comment: it is essentially the same, you are trying to return a value which is set by the ajax response...

Comment: @Sundara, the linked question is EXACTLY what you are trying to do here. As other answers said, the call is asynch, the code keeps executing. You can put `async: false` in the ajax options but that will defeat the purpose of async remote calling...

Comment: @Tallmaris  Okay i am reading.. lets  you know if i have any confusion regarding it..

Comment: @ArunPJohny You are right...   I could not see it thats why i posted this duplicate question.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh hey... You got solution of this question?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution could be something like,

```
function ajaxsessioncheck(myCallback)
            {
                var status = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>login/ajaxsessioncheck/",
                    success: function(data)
                    { 
                            //status="new value"; 
                        myCallback(data);

                    }
                });
//                alert(status)
//            return status;
            }
```

So what you probably want to do is,

```
if(ajaxsessioncheck()){
//then session still exists
}
```

but you should actually do something like,

```
ajaxsessioncheck(function(data){

  status = "new value";
  alert(status);
//go to next page 
//or do next action that is only allowed if session still exists

});
```

Also the thread mentioned in the comment by Arun P Johny ,[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) ,provides a thorough explanation of how to tackle this specific problem and the issues related to the synch and asynch behaviour of ajax requests.

Comment: okay, i am reading your answer and all posted link..

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking basic understanding of how AJAX calls work. AJAX calls are asynchronous. Your code keeps executing while the call is being processed. The code inside your success callback will only execute after the current executing code finishes (when javascript relinquishes control back to the browser) and when the AJAX request is finished. If you put the alert after status = "new value" you'll see it gets the right value.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S5w4r/2/)

An ajax call is Async by default so when you `return  status` the new value for `status` is probably not set. Either make your ajax call synchronous or define your `status` variable in the outer scope and then just set it inside the success callback.

```
var status = "";
alert(status);    
function ajaxsessioncheck(){ 
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>login/ajaxsessioncheck/",
         success: function(data){ 
              status="new value"; 
              alert(status);
              // write code for additional functionality that needs to be executed after the new value has been set for status here.. of just make a call to another function that handles further operations..
              doSomethingWithNewStatus();
         }
   });
}

ajaxsessioncheck();


function doSomethingWithNewStatus() {
 alert("Here is your new status " + status);
}
```

Comment: So basically two times checking .. ajaxsessioncheck(), i think this will make my application slow.. what you say?

Comment: I seriously doubt the above will work...

Comment: @Tallmaris check the fiddle to be sure :)

Comment: @Sundara checking two times? could you please explain more?

Comment: Why downvote?? Please leave a comment.

Comment: @LuckySoni First time it is calling `ajaxsessioncheck();` right ? then again calling `ajaxsessioncheck();`  that 2 times.... If i am doing huge task under this `ajaxsessioncheck();`  funtion then my project will be very slow...Right?   _ & i have not did any downvote, i always support people.

Comment: @Sundara Please check my code carefully.. there is just one call to `ajaxsessioncheck();` i have defined the function once and then called it just once!

Comment: Will someone tell me why a downvote?? Its not the downvote but i really don't understand the problem with my answer.. Help me learn!! :) I am happy to receive another 100 downvotes but just give me the reason!

Comment: Hi Lucky, I downvoted before you edited your answer and added working code... I removed the downvote now. :)

Comment: poor u. here another +1 to balance it:P

Comment: but keep in mind that doesn't answer the OP question. He is expecting a return from ajaxsessioncheck().

Comment: thank you :) I am glad that i am doing the things the right way.. @Tallmaris yes, i placed that `alert` in the wrong place.

Comment: @Joraid Does `returning a value` not make it available to the seeker? Is my answer not doing that?

Comment: @Joraid You are right. Does not solve my problem with this answer.

Comment: @LuckySoni You are right, your answer is not calling 2 times the same function. But you did not answer in the way how i was looking for it.  But anyway thanks for your time